# A Python program to print the longest consecutive chain of words of the same length from a sentence

Tags: python, string, list, for-loop

I got tasked with writing a Python script that would output the longest chain of consecutive words of the same length from a sentence. For example, if the input is "To be or not to be", the output should be "To, be, or".

```
text = input("Enter text: ")
words = text.replace(",", " ").replace(".", " ").split()
x = 0
same = []
same.append(words[x])

for i in words:
    if len(words[x]) == len(words[x+1]):
        same.append(words[x+1])
        x += 1
    elif len(words[x]) != len(words[x+1]):
        same = []
        x += 1
    else:
        print("No consecutive words of the same length")

print(words)
print("Longest chain of words with similar length: ", same)
```

In order to turn the string input into a list of words and to get rid of any punctuation, I used the replace() and split() methods. The first word of this list would then get appended to a new list called "same", which would hold the words with the same length. A for-loop would then compare the lengths of the words one by one, and either append them to this list if their lengths match, or clear the list if they don't.

```
if len(words[x]) == len(words[x+1]):
                         ~~~~~^^^^^
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is the problem I keep getting, and I just can't understand why the index is out of range.

I will be very grateful for any help with solving this issue and fixing the program. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you think `words[x+1]` is when `x` is the index of the last item in `words`?

Comment: if `x` has been incremented enough times so that it is the last index in the list, `x+1` will be out of range.

Comment: By the way, your loop never uses the `i` variable, which is a clue that you're using the wrong kind of loop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `groupby` you can get the result as

```
from itertools import groupby
string = "To be or not to be"
sol = ', '.join(max([list(b) for a, b in groupby(string.split(), key=len)], key=len))
print(sol)
# 'To, be, or'
```

Comment: Wonder what should be expected for a *tie* - like this:  ```S = 'To be or not too bee that is a question'```

Comment: @DanielHao more condition need to be provide by OP for that, regarding which one to consider in such case, first occurence pattern or word having more length

Comment: Agreed.  It's for OP to clarify... Sure. +1 smart use of two *keys* here

Comment: I think according to task conditions, the first occurrence pattern should be the output in such case

Answer (score -1):

len() function takes a string as an argument, for instance here in this code according to me first you have to convert the **words** variable into a list then it might work.

Thank You !!!

Comment: len() does take a string.  words is a list.  words[x] is one element in that list.  in this case words[x] is a string, so len(words[x]) is allowable.  the problem is when x is at the end of the list and len(words[x+1]) tries to reference the word AFTER the last word in the list.

Comment: @user3055756 I tried changing the script so that x = 1 initially and words[x-1] and words[x] are used instead of words[x] and words[x+1], and yet I still get the same problem. Is there a solution to this you could suggest? Thanks a lot

Comment: When you try to look at x-1 you are referencing array/list element you have almost the same problem.  When x=0 (the first element), x-1 = -1 and that is not a valid element either.  I would try to change your looping mechanism.  Now you are using "for each in list"-style mechanism that loops through all elements of words[].  Instead, use a looping mechanism that steps from 0 to the total # of words -1.  I'm learning python myself, so I don't know what looping mechanism that is (while..do?), but it is how the problem is solved in other programming languages.

Comment: @user3055756 Thanks for the suggestion, I will try a different loop and see how it works. Have a great day!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).